# Newspaper generator to InDesign: IDML or InDesign Server?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-server, idml

I'm creating a library to generate newspaper in IDML/InDesign format.

This library today already outputs the newspaper using PDFLib, which give to us all control (in points) about what is being plotted.

In our IDML version engine, we have to deal with TextFrame and Stories, but I don't have the same control as PDFLib.

I don't know if my Story fit in the TextFrame, I don't know if I need to resize it or create a new linked TextFrame to keep printing the same Story in the next column.

As the final library will be used in a server, do I need to use the InDesign Server to generate it?
Can I auto-adjust TextFrames, creating a new one if story doesn't fit into one, (and so on..) ?

Or can this control be done just using pure IDML?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need InDesign's layout engine to do it.

This was solved here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3632808.